# Sorting a Multidimensional array by day using usort not working in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

Here is the array that I want to sort by weekday(Monday to Sunday)
I've checked similar questions but none of them helped to fix this issue.

```
$data = 
     array (
          0 => 
          array (
            'mid' => 19,
            'centerid' => 1,
            'sid' => 13,
            'weekday' => 'tuesday',
            'break' => 1,
          ),
          1 => 
          array (
            'mid' => 14,
            'centerid' => 1,
            'sid' => 13,
            'weekday' => 'wednesday',
            'break' => 1,
          ),
          2 => 
          array (
            'mid' => 12,
            'centerid' => 1,
            'sid' => 13,
            'weekday' => 'monday',
            'break' => 1,
          ),
          3 => 
          array (
            'mid' => 17,
            'centerid' => 1,
            'sid' => 13,
            'weekday' => 'monday',
            'break' => 0,
          ),
        );

usort($data, array($this,'cmp'));
```

I've tried usort to sort it

```
function cmp($a, $b){

    $a = strtotime($a['weekday']);
    $b = strtotime($b['weekday']);

    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

but it is not working and is disordered. Can someone help me on this?

Comment: is that is what you want? https://eval.in/536794

Comment: I want to sort this array by weekdays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `cmp` function

```
function cmp($a, $b){
    $a = date('N', strtotime($a['weekday']));
    $b = date('N', strtotime($b['weekday']));

    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write function that maps day name into number and use it in `cmp` function:

```
<?php
$data = 
     array (
          0 => 
          array (
            'mid' => 19,
            'centerid' => 1,
            'sid' => 13,
            'weekday' => 'tuesday',
            'break' => 1,
          ),
          1 => 
          array (
            'mid' => 14,
            'centerid' => 1,
            'sid' => 13,
            'weekday' => 'wednesday',
            'break' => 1,
          ),
          2 => 
          array (
            'mid' => 12,
            'centerid' => 1,
            'sid' => 13,
            'weekday' => 'monday',
            'break' => 1,
          ),
          3 => 
          array (
            'mid' => 17,
            'centerid' => 1,
            'sid' => 13,
            'weekday' => 'monday',
            'break' => 0,
          ),
        );

usort($data, array($this,'cmp'));

function getNumberOfDayByDayName($dayName)
{
    $map = array(
        'monday'=>1,
        'tuesday'=>2,
        'wednesday'=>3,
        'thursday'=>4,
        'friday'=>5,
        'saturday'=>6,
        'sunday'=>7,
    );

    return $map[$dayName];
}

function cmp($a, $b){

    $a = getNumberOfDayByDayName($a['weekday']);
    $b = getNumberOfDayByDayName($b['weekday']);

    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
echo '</pre>';
```

Result is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [mid] => 17
            [centerid] => 1
            [sid] => 13
            [weekday] => monday
            [break] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [mid] => 12
            [centerid] => 1
            [sid] => 13
            [weekday] => monday
            [break] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [mid] => 19
            [centerid] => 1
            [sid] => 13
            [weekday] => tuesday
            [break] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [mid] => 14
            [centerid] => 1
            [sid] => 13
            [weekday] => wednesday
            [break] => 1
        )

)
```

**Working example: [CLICK](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c5f995b8ca34e6755b3b37826413fbaa7378ae26)**

Comment: My solution also works :) But solution given by @brevis is better, well done @brevis!